# How to call APIs which require authentication inside Azure Bot?

Tags: asp.net-core, botframework, asp.net-core-3.0, direct-line-botframework

Usually I generate API clients by Autorest and then use `AddHttpClient` + `AddHttpMessageHandler` or `ServiceClientCredentials` to handle requests to API and add authentication information (which send through cookies to ASP.NET Core app and available inside `HttpRequest` or I use JWT tokens and make call to another API to refresh them). But how to do something similar for Chat Bot? I can't information about user from `UserState` because it require `ITurnContext` which is not available here. And as I can understand, bot communicate with backend through steam, so there are no information about user in `HttpRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the simplest way to do it is to write a bot middleware and save `ITurnContext`, then use it to get information from `UserState`.